# Is there a bug with confirm() popups on chrome 75 (windows 7, MacOS)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm

It seems that on chrome 75, with windows 7, confirm() popups are not working properly anymore and closing immediatly.

Tried it on chrome 74 just before, it worked well !

**EDIT : This issue is also happening on MacOS**

**EDIT 2 : On the concerned website, it seems that disabling ads avoids the issue. There should be some JS conflict**

Can someone tell me if you met this issue ?

```js
    $("#addExchange").on("click", function(event){
        if(confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
            this.form.submit();
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="addExchange">Example</div>
```

Comment: How are they being called?

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that duplicates the issue here?

Comment: Nothing mentioned in the [commit messages](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log?s=14f2111f9cec919a450115ce4914f228effca58e) for 75. 76 or 77. I've put your code in to a snippet. Note that I had to add an extra `)` at the end of your code to make it work. Make sure this isn't the same in your production code. Also worth noting is that example works fine for me, `chrome 74`, albeit on windows 10.

Comment: You [don't appear to be alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651506/confirm-automatically-closing).

Comment: I mentioned on the other question I linked to above - worth mentioning here also, [there's a bug been raised](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=972456) that looks very likely to be this.

Comment: Thank you @JamesThorpe, I added info to this raised bug.