# Confirm automatically closing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm

As soon as the confirm dialog loads it closes.

This appears to have started with chrome version 75 on windows.
Unable to duplicate on users running older versions.
Some machines with version 75 have the issue others don't.
Some pages with the confirm have the issue others don't.

Comment: Hmmm... this [came up yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633041/is-there-a-bug-with-confirm-popups-on-chrome-75-windows-7) for someone else too...

Comment: sounds like a bug with google chrome...?

Comment: I have Chrome 75.0.3770.90, Windows 10 and do not get this issue.

Comment: [Here's a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=972456&q=confirm&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) for the same behaviour with an `alert`.  Sounds like it could be a real issue.